# выбрать первый столбец и сформировать массив вида

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть таблица нужно выбрать её первый столбец со значениями(tutorial,extends,rules) и сформировать из них массив с разрешением .pdf в результате должен получиться массив(tutorial.pdf,extends.pdf,rules.pdf)

```
<table id="tab_el">
<tr><td>tutorial</td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>rules</td></tr>
</table>

td=$("table#tab_el tr").find('td:first');
for(i=0;i<td.length;i++){
  td[]=td[i]+".pdf";
  return td[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = $('#tab_el tr').map(function(i, el){
    return $('td:first-child',el).text() + '.pdf';
}).get();
```